# Manage numeric Intervals on SQL

Tags: database

I want to manage some datas by intervals on my database like that :

[image: Result expected]

It is possible to do that on an unique table or I need 3 tables, one for each color (with FK) ?

Real example :

Actually, on my app I use this on a dataGridView and on my database :

[image: Real example on app]
[image: Real example on database]

It is possible to set / modify or everything on three databases. I manually add the equivalency (green) but for some number with a little different is it the same equivalency, so it's - for me - interesting to use numeric intervals

Comment: Yes, you can do it with one table, however this model is too static, adding new range or change actual would be a pain. I'd create only one table called Range(for blue and red) and other one for the green one(what does this values mean?, they don't look like intervals).

Comment: I've updated the OP with an real example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on modeling databases but this is how I solve your scenario.
I'd create two Range Tables, one for storing column values, and other one for row values, each table will have same structure but since you need to represent the final values in a matrix way i decide to consider two tables(instead of merging them in one, its possible but then you'll need more effort to showing data from "Values"). As you can see i've considered a IdEquivalency columns, this will be useful for showing the data ad needed.
Finally the table Values(for green values) has two FK(one for each range value), and the value stored.

This is still a basic idea, but I'm sure you get the point.

[image: Sample]
Considerations:
Change Table Names according what its value represent.